# memcached on 2 windows servers

Tags: c#, caching, memcached

seems theres not that much information about using memcached for windows.
i am very confused on how this works and how can i test it.
i followed this guide:
http://deanhume.com/home/blogpost/memcached-for-c----a-walkthrough/62 
works like a charm!
(using couchbase version as server, and EnyimMemcached as client c#)

so now i need to test it as distribution cache and not only localy. 
im not sure how. since when i install the server on one machine (dev) theres nothing/nowhere where i can tell the server where the other server is.
should there even be a local server of memcached on same server? or is it enough  to install the server on one remote server and set up clients that will all turn to that same server? and then the client will some how get a local version of the cache?
thanks for anyone that can shed some light.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to install the cache server on dev/client machine you need just install id in your remote server. Then you can set and get cache and receive the data from that remote cache. You have to configure the server inside the web.config or app.config or any configuration that you have or you have to configure it at run time in your code.

this is my configuration:

```
<configSections>
 <sectionGroup name="enyim.com">
      <section name="memcached" type="Enyim.Caching.Configuration.MemcachedClientSection, Enyim.Caching" />
    </sectionGroup>
```

..... 
and

```
    <enyim.com>
        <memcached>
          <servers>
            <add address="yourservername" port="11219" />
          </servers>
          <socketPool minPoolSize="10" maxPoolSize="100" connectionTimeout="00:00:01"/>
          <transcoder type="Enyim.Caching.Memcached.DefaultTranscoder, Enyim.Caching"/>
    </memcached>
</enyim.com>
```